# Почему при выводе значений массива в конце есть два мусорных значения

Tags: c

Я определяю массив типа `int` из 6 цифр и при переборе этого массива в выводе получаю мусорные значения, почему так происходит?

```
int main(void)
{
  int arr[] = {1, 4, 6, 8, 12, 20};
  int n; 

  for (n = 0; arr[n] != '\0'; n++)
   printf("%d - %d\n", n, arr[n]);

  return 0;
}
```

В выводе наблюдаю цифры:

```
0 - 1
1 - 4
2 - 6
3 - 8
4 - 12
5 - 20
6 - -1719089664 // ?
7 - -738826128  // ?
```

И почему их два, а не девять например? или не двадцать ...

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что у вас будет нулевой элемент в массиве, если вы его туда не положили?... Да и 12 и 20 - совсем не цифры :)

Comment: @Harry, я думал он определяется автоматически, `int arr[] = {1, 4, 6, 8, 12, 20, '\0'};` так будет правильнее?

Comment: Это `int` - просто пишите 0, и не мучайтесь. Нулевой символ только с строковым литералам добавляется компилятором...

Comment: @Harry, аа понял, спасибо большое

Comment: Это вам ещё повезло, что в памяти при смещении от начала массива на 8-й позиции вдруг оказался ноль. Могло вывести гораздо больше "мусора" за пределами массива. Когда работаете в Си с массивом, вашим вечным спутником будет константа, содержащая размер массива. Так как стандарными методами его размер никак не узнать.

Comment: Конец массива **можно** узнать стандартно : `n < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, да я уже догадался, спасибо

Comment: @AlexGlebe, `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` будет независимым от типа. Ну и ещё есть некие препроцессорно-сишные хитрости, чтобы обеспечить гарантию, что `array` действительно массив. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L47